# Loging in to Site

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that everytime I have been logging opening the SharePoint Stack Exchange in the browser, the entire site is to the left. I have to keep readjusting the screen so I can view the page.

Comment: What browser/OS combo are you experiencing this on?

Comment: IE9, its happening when I select my username to view my questions.

Comment: I can't say I'm experiencing the same behavior in IE9.  Are you using the 64 bit version by chance?

Comment: Yes, I am using 64 bit version.

Comment: Try using the 32 bit version of IE9 and see if that resolves the issue.  64 bit has a lot of issues associated with it in the general web and Sharepoint specifically.

Comment: Thank you. (:-)

Answer (score 3):

Use 32 bit IE9 over 64 bit, it's just too buggy.